# logstash grok issue while filtering data

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

I have a data that's basically for data deletion via rm command which looks as follows.

```
ttmv516,19/05/21,03:59,00-mins,dvcm,dvcm 166820 4.1 0.0 4212 736 ? DN 03:59 0:01 rm -rf /dv/project/agile/mce_dev_folic/test/install.asan/install,/dv/svgwwt/commander/workspace4/dvfcronrun_IL-SFV-RHEL6.5-K4_kinite_agile_invoke_dvfcronrun_at_given_site_50322
```

I'm using below logstash grok on this, which was working fine but until recently i see two weird issue 1) `_grokparsefailure`  another 2) `Hostname Field` not appearing correctly ie its initial chars are not there like `ttmv516` would appear like `mv516`.

```
%{HOSTNAME:Hostname},%{DATE:Date},%{HOUR:dt_h}:%{MINUTE:dt_m},%{NUMBER:duration}-%{WORD:hm},%{USER:User},%{USER:User_1} %{NUMBER:Pid} %{NUMBER:float} %{NUMBER:float} %{NUMBER:Num_1} %{NUMBER:Num_2} %{DATA} (?:%{HOUR:dt_h1}:|)(?:%{MINUTE:dt_m1}|) (?:%{HOUR:dt_h2}:|)(?:%{MINUTE:dt_m2}|)%{GREEDYDATA:CMD},%{GREEDYDATA:PWD_PATH}
```

However, testing same with grok Debugger in Kibana data appears correctly.

[image]

My logstash file as follows.

```
cat /etc/logstash/conf.d/rmlog.conf
input {
  file {
    path => [ "/data/rm_logs/*.txt" ]
    start_position => beginning
    sincedb_path => "/data/registry-1"
    max_open_files => 64000
    type => "rmlog"
  }
}

filter {
  if [type] == "rmlog" {
    grok {
     match => { "message" => "%{HOSTNAME:Hostname},%{DATE:Date},%{HOUR:dt_h}:%{MINUTE:dt_m},%{NUMBER:duration}-%{WORD:hm},%{USER:User},%{USER:User_1} %{NUMBER:Pid} %{NUMBER:float} %{NUMBER:float} %{NUMBER:Num_1} %{NUMBER:Num_2} %{DATA} (?:%{HOUR:dt_h1}:|)(?:%{MINUTE:dt_m1}|) (?:%{HOUR:dt_h2}:|)(?:%{MINUTE:dt_m2}|)%{GREEDYDATA:CMD},%{GREEDYDATA:PWD_PATH}" }
      add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
      remove_field => [ "@version", "host", "message", "_type", "_index", "_score" ]
   }
  }
 }
output {
        if [type] == "rmlog" {
        elasticsearch {
                hosts => ["myhost.xyz.com:9200"]
                manage_template => false
                index => "pt-rmlog-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
  }
 }
}
```

Any help suggestion would highly be appreciated.

### EDIT:

Messages on which its failing as per my observation ..

```
ttmv540,19/05/21,03:59,00-hrs,USER,USER PID %CPU %MEM VSZ RSS TTY STAT START TIME COMMAND,/local/ntr/ttmv540.373
ttmv541,19/05/21,03:43,-mins,USER,USER PID %CPU %MEM VSZ RSS TTY STAT START TIME COMMAND,/local/ntr/ttmv541.373
```

However, i have tried to edit the grok with below condition but still it drops the the few fields..

```
input {
  file {
    path => [ "/data/rm_logs/*.txt" ]
    start_position => beginning
    max_open_files => 64000
    sincedb_path => "/data/registry-1"
    type => "rmlog"
  }
}
filter {
  if [type] == "rmlog" {
    grok {
     match => { "message" => "%{HOSTNAME:hostname},%{DATE:date},%{HOUR:time_h}:%{MINUTE:time_m},%{NUMBER:duration}-%{WORD:hm},%{USER:user},%{USER:group} %{NUMBER:pid} %{NUMBER:float} %{NUMBER:float} %{NUMBER:num_1} %{NUMBER:num_2} %{DATA} (?:%{HOUR:time_h1}:|)(?:%{MINUTE:time_m1}|) (?:%{HOUR:time_h2}:|)(?:%{MINUTE:time_m2}|)%{GREEDYDATA:cmd},%{GREEDYDATA:pwd}" }
      add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
      remove_field => [ "@version", "host", "message", "_type", "_index", "_score" ]
   }
  }
  if "_grokparsefailure" in [tags] {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{HOSTNAME:hostname},%{DATE:date},%{HOUR:time_h}:%{MINUTE:time_m},-%{WORD:duration},%{USER:user},%{USER:group}%{GREEDYDATA:cmd}" }
      add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
      remove_field => [ "@version", "host", "message", "_type", "_index", "_score" ]
  }
 }
}
output {
        if [type] == "rmlog" {
        elasticsearch {
                hosts => ["myhost.xyz.com:9200"]
                manage_template => false
                index => "pt-rmlog-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
  }
 }
}
```

Note: Looks like `_grokparsefailure` tag works on the below messages but still fails on another..

1) this works..

```
 ttmv541,19/05/21,03:43,-mins,USER,USER PID %CPU %MEM VSZ RSS TTY STAT START TIME COMMAND,/local/ntr/ttmv541.373

ttmv540,19/05/21,03:59,00-hrs,USER,USER PID %CPU %MEM VSZ RSS TTY STAT START TIME COMMAND,/local/ntr/ttmv540.373
```

2) Second line of text log fails because it has `00-hrs` number associated with it, now not getting to meet both conditions with below grok ..

```
%{HOSTNAME:hostname},%{DATE:date},%{HOUR:time_h}:%{MINUTE:time_m},-%{WORD:duration},%{USER:user},%{USER:group}%{GREEDYDATA:cmd}
```

Comment: Does the Logstash grok filter always fail on every entry? Or does it work for some and not for others? If it only works on some entries, can you give more examples? Try to modify the script so you don't remove the "message" field and see how it looks like on the entries where grok failed to parse.

Comment: It works mostly fails for some cases, i got few cases where it fails, let me update those.

Comment: @mihomir, i just update the post with new thing i applied

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd split the processing into two parts, one to deal with the hostname and timestamp issues, and one to handle the rest of the row.  I find this makes maintenance easier.

So you're left with these two inputs:

```
ttmv541,19/05/21,03:43,-mins
ttmv540,19/05/21,03:59,00-hrs
```

Your two patterns will match the first pieces well, so the issue is how you want to parse out the stuff after the time.  In your original pattern, you were using `duration` for the numeric part and `hm` for the units.  In your second pattern, you seem to put the units into `duration`, which probably isn't right.

Without more information, it looks like the duration is optional, but you'll always have the units.  That can be reflected in your pattern, e.g.:

```
(%{NUMBER:duration})?-%{WORD:hm}
```

Also note that if you ever end up needing multiple patterns, you don't have to depend on the grokparsefailure to use them - match->message can take an array.  See [the doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html#plugins-filters-grok-match) for an example.

Comment: @Alan, thanks a mile for this awesome advise +1 , i'm testing this out

Comment: Alan, if you dont mind, can you explain `Also note that if you ever end up needing multiple patterns, you don't have to depend on the grokparsefailure to use them - match->message can take an array.`

Comment: I added a link to the doc.  You can give match multiple patterns to use.